# How to find closest double in unsorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, search, optimization

I have a set of points in discrete space and coordinates are given as N double[] arrays.

Such as:

Point T1 = {1.3,2.5,4-3} ---> double[] x = {1.3}, double[] y = {2.5}, double[] z = {4.3}

Then I have a function which generates an offset from a given point in all directions in continuous space and I need to find closest match in my matrix/double array.

The problem is that I cannot sort these arrays and apply binary search, because components of Point will most likely not have the same indexes after sort, with respect to each other.

Is there some data structure/algorithm which I could apply to avoid iterative searching for the closest matching point?

Would it be better to organize points such that there is one array instance describing entire point rather than array per component ?

**Edit**

It looks like the ideal solution would utilize k-d trees as suggested in comment. Computer science algorithms are not my domain and therefore an answer demonstrating minimal example with k-d trees, or some alternative, would be most helpful while I am researching the topic.

Comment: Do all `N` double[] contain only a single element?

Comment: You can use an [Octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) or some other spatial data type like a k-D tree

Comment: I am not bound to any structure. What i need to be able to is somehow store Points in Dimensional space to get as fast as possible search. Any data organization which does take that into account works for me.

Comment: The solution should not be tied to 3 dimensional space

Comment: Looks like, from what i can read, that k-d tree might be the solution for this. I have never used this structure before. @Samgak could you perhaps demonstrate smallest possible example for the answer?

Comment: If I understand your problem, you have N arrays of size M of floats, each one containing the coordinate of a point along an axis in an N - dimensional space. You also have a single float, and you want to find the index of the point for which the float is closest to one of the components. If that's correct I would create a single array whose elements are pairs (value, index), with value being one of the components, and index bring the index of the point the component belongs to. You can then sort the array using value as the sorting.key. at that point you can use a binary search using the float

Comment: I have neighbor function which generates offset in all/some directions from given point. This will give me another Point which exists in Real space but not in my sampled space. So i need to find closest matching point in sampled space.

Comment: Why are you using 3 separate arrays and not one array of a point type? Then you could sort by whatever criteria and coordinates will be kept together.

Comment: How would this reduce time complexity of closest match for target Point? How would i write sort criteria for N dimensional Points ? If two points are equal in 10 dimensions and differ in two, which one should have lower index ? Even if i had sorted array of Points like that, how would i preform binary search for closest match over n dimensions ? On the second thought this would not be sufficient and would only guarantee local matches, not global.

Comment: Is your set of points to search constant? Or dynamic?

Comment: Sampled points are constant. Points which are calculated from Real space are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem, you have N arrays of size M of floats, each one containing the coordinate of a point along an axis in an N - dimensional space. You also have a single float, and you want to find the index of the point for which the float is closest to one of the components. If that's correct I would create a single array whose elements are pairs (value, index), with value being one of the components, and index bring the index of the point the component belongs to. You can then sort the array using value as the sorting.key. at that point you can use a binary search using the float.

Of course building and sorting the array makes sense only if you have multiple floats to search for, as sorting will take O (K log K), with K= N*M, and searching after that will take O (log K). If you only have to search for one float, you might as well do a full search on the array, which will be O (K).

Comment: I don't have single float as distance. I have N doubles (step in N directions) which represent new Point, not a single Float showing step in one direction. And i need to find closest match of such new Point against one i have in my sample.

Comment: Is it a single point in the N - dimensional space,, or any number of them? If a single point P, just traverse the entire array and collect the minimum distance point from P. If you have to search any number of points P,  then you may want to lookup "Nearest Neighbor  search" on wikipedia.

Comment: Searching the entire array is what i wanted to avoid. Granted, it would work but the premise of question is how to write more efficient algorithm than that. There will not be only one step in the space, followed with search for closest neighbor, hence i wanted least time complexity.

Comment: Thanks, I will check nearest neighbor as you suggest.